# recursive function returns undefined on second run

Tags: javascript, jquery, recursion

I have a recursive function that runs over my object (nested object with children) and it returns an object back as a result (which works as it should), but when the function is called within another function, the second time the function runs it returns undefined.

this is the initiator:

```
$('a').click(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass('open')){
        return null;
    }
    console.log(this);
    var parentId = $(this).attr('id');
    var children = searchForChildrenByParentId(currentParentObject, parentId);
    console.log(children);
    if(children){
        var ul = $(this).children();
        children.forEach(function(child){
            var li = addLi(child);
            applyLiToUl(ul, li);
            init();
        })
    }
    $(this).addClass('open');
})
```

and the recursive function:

```
function searchForChildrenByParentId(obj, stack){
    for (var property in obj) {
        if (property == "id") {
            if(obj.id == stack ){
                console.log(obj.children);
                return obj.children;
            } else if (obj.hasOwnProperty("children")){
                obj.children.forEach(function(child){
                    searchForChildrenByParentId(child, stack);
                })
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The recursive function does its job as it should, works great, the initiator also works (on the first run).

The first console.log in the initiator returns the correct element,
the console log (in the recursive function) logs the correct object, but when the object is returned to the initiator the console log there gives me undefined?

Comment: In the "children" case, nothing is returned (well, `undefined` is returned) because there's no `return` statement.

Comment: @Pointy not sure if I understood you correctly, but if you're talking about the recursive function, it should run over the whole object until it finds and object.id which is equal to stack (some id) and that statement is mandatory, therefore thats the only statement that returns an object

Comment: What is `currentParentObject`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so the problem was my understanding of recursion, even tho the function gave me the right object the recursion still kept on going, therefore returning me an undefined object. what I did was assign the result of the recursion to a global variable and using that variable to my next task

```
     var childOfParentObject; //outside the function - in global scope

     if(obj.id == stack ){
        console.log(obj.children);
        obj.children = childOfParentObject;
        return childOfParentObject;  

     }
```

did the trick